# Google map application program crashes at the launch

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I have been trying to add a map to my application, I have followed instructions on the android developers HelloGoogleMaps tutorial but my map is just force closing when I run the maps option. I have obtained my api key logged permissions in manifest

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.MappDemo.mymaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MappingDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ShowTheMap" android:label="Lat/Long Location"> </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MapMe" android:label="Track Present Location"> </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can some one tell if any thing needs to be configured in addition to run the code?

```
03-25 11:50:52.217: I/Process(687): Sending signal. PID: 687 SIG: 9
03-25 11:51:00.557: D/AndroidRuntime(729): Shutting down VM
03-25 11:51:00.567: W/dalvikvm(729): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.MappDemo.mymaps/com.MappDemo.mymaps.MappingDemoActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.MappDemo.mymaps.MappingDemoActivity
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.MappDemo.mymaps.MappingDemoActivity
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at com.MappDemo.mymaps.MappingDemoActivity.onCreate(MappingDemoActivity.java:19)
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-25 11:51:00.627: E/AndroidRuntime(729):  ... 11 more
03-25 11:51:10.013: I/Process(729): Sending signal. PID: 729 SIG: 9
03-25 11:52:16.817: D/AndroidRuntime(782): Shutting down VM
03-25 11:52:16.817: W/dalvikvm(782): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.MappDemo.mymaps/com.MappDemo.mymaps.MappingDemoActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.MappDemo.mymaps.MappingDemoActivity
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.MappDemo.mymaps.MappingDemoActivity
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at com.MappDemo.mymaps.MappingDemoActivity.onCreate(MappingDemoActivity.java:19)
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-25 11:52:16.877: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  ... 11 more
```

this is what I can see in logcat..
this what I have in mappingDemoActivity.java

```
public class MappingDemoActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //add listners for all buttons
        View firstbutton= findViewById(R.id.geocode_button);
        firstbutton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        View secondButton = findViewById(R.id.latlong_button);
        secondButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        View thirdButton = findViewById(R.id.presentLocation_button);
        thirdButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.geocode_button:
             Log.i("Button","Button 1 pushed");
             Intent j = new Intent(this, ShowTheMap.class);
             startActivity(j);
         break;

         case R.id.latlong_button:
             Log.i("Button","Button 2 pushed");
             Intent k = new Intent(this, ShowTheMap.class);
             startActivity(k);
         break;

         case R.id.presentLocation_button:
             Log.i("Button","Button 3 pushed");
             Intent m = new Intent(this, MapMe.class);
             startActivity(m);
         break; 
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you add the exception that you are getting in the DDMS... So that we can get an idea on your issue.

Comment: I have put the error .. Please let me know where am i actually going wrong??

Comment: Are you using the Google API Simulator ?

Comment: yea i m using the same.Is it a problem with the simulator?or any thing that i dint configure?

Comment: Seems like This is due to ClassCastException.Paste the line 19 in MappingDemoActivity.java

Comment: post MappingDemoActivity.java,,post line no 19 ...

Answer (score 0):

`<uses-permission>` tag needs to be a child of `<manifest>`, not `<application>`.
Try change `<uses-permission>` position, it can help.

Comment: i did that even. but same prob.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code which is inside  `<intent-filter>`

```
`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`
```

Because it is Already there in Below Quote.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Google MapsDemo that is included in the SDK my path is:

**C:\android-sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google_inc_-10\samples\MapsDemo**

I had a quite anoying problem ([MapActivity crashes on some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205785/mapview-mapactivity-crash-on-some-devices)) that was only showing up on certain(!) Android devices and also not in the Emulator. What I did was, to strip down the working demo until it was similar to my basic example. Then it turned out that Samsung phones don't accept package names not starting with **com.**, while other devices (HTC Flyer) do! But this is not your problem, since you are using a **com.** package name.

There might be one more thing that comes to my mind. You didn't post your main.xml. If you use a nested LinearLayout below the MapView this also crashes the app. On top of the MapView it works fine. So in case you are using something like:

```
<LinearLayout ... >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView ... />

    <LinearLayout ... >
        <Button .../>   
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This could cause your problem. This is reproducable and throws exactly the same **java.lang.ClassCastException** error.

Also be sure to have your **< uses-permission >** and **< uses-library >** statements in the right place, as the guys said before. The first one must be a direct child of the **< manifest >** node. The second one must be a direct child of the **< application >** node.

I hope this helps you. I was going crazy with this stuff.

Bernd