# MapView / MapActivity crash on some devices

Tags: android, crash, android-mapview, oncreate, mapactivity

I have gone through Google's MapView tutorial and it works fine on the emulator and for example on my HTC Flyer. But for some reason it immediately crashes when starting it on my mobile phone (Samsung Galaxy I9000).

The crash happens there, because right at the beginning the Bundle that onCreate() receives is null. I'm compiling against Android 2.3.3. This is installed on the phone as well. The Flyer uses Android 3.0

I'd greatly appreciate any help on this weird issue.

This is the excact Logcat output:

```
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bernd.konnerth/bernd.konnerth.HelloMapViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileOutput(ContextImpl.java:495)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:158)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.android.AndroidPersistentStore.writeBlockX(AndroidPersistentStore.java:140)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.android.AndroidPersistentStore.writeBlock(AndroidPersistentStore.java:169)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.PreferenceStore.ensurePreferencesLoaded(PreferenceStore.java:178)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.PreferenceStore.readPreference(PreferenceStore.java:86)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.BasePersistentStore.readPreference(BasePersistentStore.java:41)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.StaticUtil.readPreferenceAsDataInput(StaticUtil.java:271)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.loadOrRequestCookie(DataRequestDispatcher.java:493)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.<init>(DataRequestDispatcher.java:390)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.createInstance(DataRequestDispatcher.java:341)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.createMap(MapActivity.java:548)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:422)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at bernd.konnerth.HelloMapViewActivity.onCreate(HelloMapViewActivity.java:15)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
04-18 10:52:26.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks,
Bernd

Comment: see this [example](http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/map-api-in-android.html) will help you...

Comment: what is the Logccat output exactly?

Comment: I've added it above now.

Comment: Thanks, i will try. But somehow the **mains.xml** seems to be missing, which is referenced in **setContentView(R.layout.mains)**

Comment: put this in ur mains.xml

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:apiKey="YOUR API KEY"
        android:clickable="true" />

Comment: I got a solution! Obviously the package name needs to start with **com.**. I would like to explain in detail, but why the hell am I not allowed to answer my own question within 8 hours ???

Comment: I haven't tried it, because I found the solution mentioned above. But when I look into that example I see that **march.fifteen** was used as package name. So the example would probably not have worked as well. Nevertheless, thanks for your fast reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it! Guess what! It's the package name that matters!!!

I found a Google Map sample in:

**C:\android-sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google_inc_-10\samples\MapsDemo**

then I stripped it down until it was nearly identical to my one. I was using **bernd.konnerth** as the package name. But for some really crazy reason, obviously the Samsung phone (and probably other devices as well) does not accept that and simply throws a NullPointerException at launch, without any further hint that could point to the package name issue.

When I use **com.bernd.konnerth** everything works fine. Obviously there must be a **com.** in front. But be warned! There seem to be further name combinations that don't work. By chance I found out that for example **com.android.wifi** doesn't work as well! Even thought this package does NOT seem to exist in android namespace.

Such things can really drive people crazy! :-(

Nevertheless thanks for all of your fast replies!

Bernd

Comment: If only I could give you more than a single +1...
Many thanks!

Comment: Happy to hear that my findings helped you! :-)

Comment: @Bernd Could you check my question, I am having similar issue, if it's relevant to your fix? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56697628/using-mapactivity-for-mapview-crashes-application-only-on-marshmallow-6-0-6-0

Comment: @hemanthkumar, thanks, but I must admit that its quite a while ago that I was dealing with Android. I don't have my environment setup anymore. So I can't check what you suggested. Sorry.

Comment: @Bernd no worries. Thanks Anyways.