# The strangest Android crash occurring to about 20 users of my app

Tags: java, android, debugging, crash

I've been getting crash reports recently about a crash that is occurring to 20 out of about 200,000 users.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileOutput(ContextImpl.java:429)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:158)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:158)
at nor.b(Unknown Source)
at nor.a(Unknown Source)
at ogl.f(Unknown Source)
at ogl.b(Unknown Source)
at ogl.a(Unknown Source)
at ofb.g(Unknown Source)
at ohz.g(Unknown Source)
at oiq.run(Unknown Source)
```

This crash is obviously not part of my code, and I couldn't even find any classes with those 3-letter package names. It's occurring on Android 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.7, 4.0.4 and 4.0.9.

These are the libraries that are used in my project, is it possible that one of them has caused it?

- BugSense
- Google Maps API v2
- Google Play Services
- Jackson
- Android Support Library
- ActionBarSherlock

I really have no idea how to prevent this crash from occurring, I tried searching Google for these class names but found no results.

My application is not pro-guarded.

Thanks,

Elad

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but i would assume that those 3 letter classes are generated by Proguard, did you use it on your app?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did not use ProGuard in my app but possibly one of the libraries did?

Comment: "I couldn't even find any classes with those 3-letter package names" -- that is from ProGuard. "My application is not pro-guarded" -- the Play Services SDK is.

Comment: I see - so if the Play Services SDK is crashing there is no way I can fix that crash, right? I don't even know which part of my code caused it to crash.

Comment: While this is not your code, the crash CAN happen because of your code, if a null object propagates down to the crashing code. Try to find which line of your code triggers the crash, this would be useful information

Comment: Go through [this][1] and [this][2]. It might help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259421/nullpointerexception-at-openfileoutput-in-activity
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055037/unable-to-start-activity-caused-by-nullpointerexception-at-contextimpl-openfileo